# ZXing IntentResult gives null value

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, qr-code, zxing

I am using ZXing library to create a qr code scanner..IntentResult gives null value and the scanner does not work...please help...thank you!!

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(result != null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(result.getContents() == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scanning Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: what is resultCode that u r getting ?

Comment: the scanner does not work: what does that mean did it scanned something or just return null result. Share more details

Comment: zero @GaneshPatil

Comment: scanner opens but as soon as i scan a qr code,it goes back to previous activity without any response and the toast displayed is out i.e. result is null @Killer